# Local Copy Error in PrestaShop 1.6.1.0 it's impossible for me to run PrestaShop locally

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Firstly, I want to create a local copy of it, but I can't seem to retrieve the complete database. When I try to back it up, an error message appears. Despite this, the backup is completed, but the created file is partial, and some tables are missing. Without the complete database, it's impossible for me to run PrestaShop locally. How can I resolve this issue?

[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBdXk.png)

[backup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2lVr.png)

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty straightforward: you should increase your PHP memory_limit
setting to an higher value to let the backup script completes correctly.

Anyway I would suggest you to dump your database at a lower level, ie. from your
shell command line or using a tool like PhpMyAdmin.